# Pagination link not working fine codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

The pagination links show up fine, but when I select link 2 the result is not being displayed and the url is changing to `/kkci/searchresult/users/1`, when it should change to `/kkci/searchresult/users/2`.

When I select the next numeric link, data is not being fetched. So what might be the error? I'm not able to get an answer through google, and I'm not sure what happens, so I am posting my code below please go through it and and help me.

Thing is that that when I click on number 2 of pagination link, `echo var_dump()` shows `Result` is empty and I am not getting any values for `echo $data->email`.
But one recored is being displayed when the page load problem is when I select pagination link it is not working.

I'm new to CI asking CI guys to help me in displaying result for pagination 2 and 3. In total, I have 3 records I'm displaying a single record for page.

I have gone through script many times but it was no use so atlast posting here to find a solution .

**Controller:**

```
public function users($limit=1,$offset = 0)
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');
    if ($postdata = $this->session->flashdata('post_data')) {
        foreach (unserialize($postdata) as $key => $value) {
            $_POST[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('post_data', serialize($this->input->post()));
    $data = array();

    $look = $this->input->post('look');
    $age = $this->input->post('age');
    $age_from = $this->input->post('age_from');
    $age_to = $this->input->post('age_to');
    $se_ct = $this->input->post('sect');
    $subsect = $this->input->post('subsect');
    $coun_try = $this->input->post('country');
    $sta_te = $this->input->post('state');
    $ci_ty = $this->input->post('city');
    $qualification = $this->input->post('qualification');

    $results = $this->searchresultss->login($look, $age, $age_to, $age_from, $se_ct, $subsect, $coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty, $qualification);

    //for base_url()
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url("searchresult/users/");
    $config['total_rows'] = count($results);
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $this->load->library('pagination', $config);
    $data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['results'] = array_slice($results, $offset, $limit);
    $this->load->view('searchresult', $data); 
}
```

**Model**

```
public function login($look, $age, $age_to, $age_from, $se_ct, $subsect, $coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty, $qualification)
{    
    return $this->db->query("
        SELECT *
            FROM users
            WHERE   

           gender = '$look'
        And status='1'"
    )->result(); //Returning this to controller    
 }
```

**View**

```
if (empty($results)) {
    echo 'Results set is empty';
} else {
    foreach ($results as $data) {
        echo $data->email.'<br />';
    }
} 

echo $pagination_links;//Iam able to display pagination link in my view page.
```

I am new to ci so request ci guys to help me on pagination script.

Thanks in advance for Helping me.

Comment: $this->pagination->crecreate_links(); should be $this->pagination->create_links();

Comment: oh it was mistake while posting..it already $this->pagination->create_links(); thing is that when page gets refresh by selecting the pagnation link the search variable are beign lost from session

Comment: I think you're posting so much code, if your problem is only with pagination, avoid all the "post code" in the controller, comment it out and check pagination only with fixed values, to know if everything is in order with it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow wow wow... You're sending no `$offset` at all! So, as you stated in your Controller, the offset is 0, so you'll never get a result in

```
$data['results'] = array_slice($results, $offset, $limit);
```

**Solution:**

Change the method declaration from

```
public function users($limit=1,$offset = 0)
```

to

```
public function users($limit=1,$offset = 10)
```

or be always sure you're sending the offset in your URL:

```
/kkci/searchresult/users/1/10
```

I think your problem could be with the pagination url that you're sending, can you inspect the destination it shows?because maybe your link `href` is something like `/kkci/searchresult/users//1`, and that would explain why you always goes to page 1: Ci gets the value as empty, and it states it as 1. If that is also the case, change from

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url("searchresult/users/");`
```

to

```
// Note that I removed the trailing slash:
$config['base_url'] = base_url("searchresult/users");
```

Anyway, you should check the offset value before using it, and restrain the number of results giben back in your SQL, because when you'll have a table with a few thousands of results, it'll be easy paginate them with SQL using LIMIT 10, 20 than a PHP slice array of a crazily big array. Ah, and when the number of rows returned is "I don't exactly remember the number but I think was about 3000", CodeIgniter Active Record won't will you back more than .

Comment: Hi chococroc ... i met wth an accident so could nt able to follow u as well as the project...

Comment: problem with my pagination scripts still exits not able to solve it..can you please ..i will be thankful

Comment: yeah, no problem, but what did you do at the end? Did you try proposed above? what are the results? what happens with it?